# How to get the li value for localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, local-storage

this is part of my coding

```
function getStudentList() {
    $.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getStudents.php?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
        $('#studentList li').remove();
        $('#load').hide();
        //students = data.user_name;
        $.each(data, function(index, student) {
            $('#studentList').append('<li><a href="student_detail.html?user_name=' + student.data.user_name + '">' +
                    '<h4>' + student.data.user_name + '</h4>' +
                    '<p>' + student.data.role + '</p>' +
                    '</a></li>');
        });
        $('#studentList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

i have seen some posts that phonegap may not support the URL like student_detail.html?user_name=XXXX, is it right? therefore, i would like to change the approach by using localStorage. studentList will generate a list of students, i would like to show users the details of the chosen student. once the student is selected, his username will be stored in localStorage, and get the value in other page for further processing. next time , when the users want to see another student, that localStorage will firstly deleted, and create new. is this approach ok? and, my question is how can I save the value of chosen student;s username?

```
var id = $("#id").val();
window.localStorage["id"] = id;
```

i dunnno how to create a specific #id inside $.each

Comment: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/   by referencing this post, i wondering why he can use the URL like student_detail.html?user_name=XXXX ?

Comment: PhoneGap shouldn't have a problem accessing the URL you describe if you've set up the project correctly. Have you added the domain where getStudents.html and student_detail.html resides to the PhoneGap project domain whitelist?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Also, because this is a PhoneGap project, the link to student_detail.html will need to be an absolute URL e.g. http://mydomain.com/student_detail.html?user_name=...

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap treats relative URLs as if they were local files (file://) included in the project.

If `student_detail.html` is resident on a server, you should address it with a fully qualified URL e.g. `http://mydomain.com/student_detail.html?user_name=...`

You also need to ensure that `http://mydomain.com` is whitelisted in the PhoneGap project as per http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

As for assigning an ID to each `li`, just add it to your template:

```
... .append('<li id="' + student.data.user_name + '"> ...')
```